# How to tell if my iOS app is making the api request

Tags: ios, api, security, csrf

We have an open API and I was wondering how I could securely tell if my own app is making the api request. I recently figured this out on android (use the sha1 fingerprint), what would the iOS equivalent of this be?

Here's a quote from the android question that was asked:

> I have an android app. Now I want that only my App can access my database on server. I know any body can decompile my app and can find the API urls and can access my database from the browser. Is there any way to protect my database from such API calls which are not generated by my Android App ?
>   I want to add any secret in Android App which change or destroy if anybody de-compile my Android App.

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-check-if-that-API-call-is-from-my-Android-app-or-from-outside-on-the-server-side

Comment: I presume the app isn't intended for the app store? Have you considered making yourself a certificate authority and generating your own certificates and then baking them into the apps, so that any traffic not originating from the apps won't succeed?

Comment: you need to make sure you specify the endpoints in a separate textfile/xml file and pass it to the url request, so that no one knows what URL u r using! I think its hard to crack the app and see the resources in it!

Comment: This is for the app store, and I want to allow people to use the URLS! I just want to know how I can securely tell if it is my app making the request, or someone else. What can I do that people won't be able to spoof, like what they did for android above.